# Установка иконки для приложения Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

При создании проекта Xamarin Android в Visual Studio в папке проекта создаётся несколько папок mipmap-..., хранящих варианты значка приложения для разные разрешений экранов устройств. Просто заменить значки на свои не удалось - иконка оставалась прежней (по умолчанию при создании проекта). Только после добавления своего значка в папку drawable и указания его названия в манифесте получилось это сделать. Отсюда вопрос - что делать с кучей ненужных уже папок mipmap-... и как сделать варианты своего значка для разных разрешений дисплеев?

Comment: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: Вопрос не в том, как создать значки, а в том, как их установить. Когда я пробовал заменить значки по умолчанию в папках mipmap-... на свои я пользовался как раз этим инструментом.